# MSBuild Task on TFS 2018 failing with the wrong .net SDK Path

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, msbuild-task, .net-core-3.1, azure-devops-server

I have a MSBuild task to build a service fabric project on TFS 2018 [On-Premises]. The solution builds fine locally using Visual Studio 2019 and MSBuild. It fails on the TFS Build Agent with the error..

> Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.

I explicitly configured the MSBuild task to use "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"

I am using the MSBuild task with the following parameters..

> /p:Deterministic=true /t:Package /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\applicationpackage

The TFS Build agent has both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 installed. It also has the .Net core SDK 3.1 installed. [3.1.100 version].

For some reason the build output shows that the SDK is being picked up from "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.602".
It needs to use the SDK from "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100"

How do I force MSBuild task to use the SDK from C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100.

I cannot add the "Nuget tools installer" task to the pipeline as our build agent does not have access to internet​

NOTE: The project was building fine using MSBuild from Visual Studio 2017 build task in TFS when we were on .net core 2.2.

We had to upgrade one the projects to .net core 3.1 and VS 2019 and it broke the build in TFS.

Contents of SFProj File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets=";ValidateMSBuildFiles">
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
<ProjectGuid>3b02cfa3-a4c3-49ea-9186-64ae171d64a7</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectVersion>2.3</ProjectVersion>
<MinToolsVersion>1.5</MinToolsVersion>
<SupportedMSBuildNuGetPackageVersion>1.6.7</SupportedMSBuildNuGetPackageVersion>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
  <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform>x64</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
<ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
  <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  <Platform>x64</Platform>
</ProjectConfiguration>
 </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
<None Include="ApplicationParameters\Local.1Node.xml" />
<None Include="ApplicationParameters\Local.5Node.xml" />
<None Include="PublishProfiles\Local.1Node.xml" />
<None Include="PublishProfiles\Local.5Node.xml" />
<None Include="Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
<Content Include="ApplicationPackageRoot\ApplicationManifest.xml" />
<Content Include="ApplicationParameters\Params.xml" />
<Content Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>

<ProjectReference Include="..\Stateful1.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
<ApplicationProjectTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Service Fabric Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationProject.targets</ApplicationProjectTargetsPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(ApplicationProjectTargetsPath)" Condition="Exists('$(ApplicationProjectTargetsPath)')" />
      <Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets')" />
  <Target Name="ValidateMSBuildFiles" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props')" Text="Unable to find the '..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props' file. Please restore the 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild' Nuget package." />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets')" Text="Unable to find the '..\..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.7\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets' file. Please restore the 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild' Nuget package." />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Add a command-line task to execute `dotnet --info` command before your other tasks, check if the 3.1.1 sdk is in use in that agent. Maybe the 3.1.100 agent is not installed well in that agent, update VS2019 to latest 16.4 and reinstall the .net core 3.1.1 sdk to resolve that issue.

Comment: Also, you can add a [use .net core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) with version 3.1.100 before your other tasks to specify the sdk version . But It's more recommended to update VS2019 and reinstall .net core sdk in local agent instead of using this task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we went with a dedicated dotnet pool with only the VS 2019 build told installed. It's working now. Looks like, if we have VS 2017 and VS 2019 on the same agent machine, it's picking up VS 2017 build tools causing VS 2019 builds to fail.

Answer (score 3):

> The TFS Build agent has both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 installed. It
>   also has the .Net core SDK 3.1 installed. [3.1.100 version].
>
> For some reason the build output shows that the SDK is being picked up
>   from "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.602". It needs to use the SDK
>   from "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100"

**To locate the cause of the issue:**

Add a [command-line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) before your msbuild task, let it execute `dotnet --info` command to output the real sdk version used in your build. Check if it's using 3.1.100 version.

(Normally, `dotnet --info` will output available latest sdk version)

**Possible Workarounds:**

1.For agent itself: Since `.net core SDK 3.1.100` supports VS2019 16.4 and above. So trying updating your VS2019 in TFS agent to latest version, and right-click `.net core project` in VS to check if 3.1 is available in drop-down list:

[image]

Sometimes you may need to reinstall or repair the [.net core 3.1.100 sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

2.For Build:You can add use [.net core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) before your other tasks in build.

[image]

[image]

Specify this task to use `3.1.100` version and then subsequent tasks(MSBuild task) will also use this version.

**Note**: `Use .net core task` will take several minutes to download and install specified .net core sdk. So it's more recommended to configure sdk manually in local agent. Hope it helps :)

Comment: We cannot use ".Net core task" as we don't have Internet access from the build agent. dotnet --info shows 3.1.100 and all the preious sdk as available. I will try repair. Although we installed VS 2019 on the agent, is this required? Can we only install MSBuild for 2019? why is the full VS 2019 required?

Comment: The free `Msbuild for VS2019` is enough. But as I mentioned above, no matter the VS2019 or MSbuild for VS2019, you should make sure the version is at least 16.4.0 and above!

Comment: @teeboy Hi friend, is there any update after your VS repair or installation of msbuild build tool package? Feel free to contact me with the details if the issue persists to block you :)

Comment: we went with a dedicated dotnet pool with only the VS 2019 build told installed. It's working now. Looks like, if we have VS 2017 and VS 2019 on the same agent machine, it's picking up VS 2017 build tools causing VS 2019 builds to fail.